# JS - value of "data-original-title" passing to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html code, with a function to download content as plain text:

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a id="fileNameId" data-toggle="pill" href="#tab" style="font-weight:bold">Server Name
            <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt text-primary tips pull-right" type="button" onclick="downloadFile('fileNameId', 'contentId')" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Download1" style="display:block"> </button>
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <pre id="contentId">Some text to download</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
    function downloadFile(fileNameId, contentId) {
        var element = document.createElement('a');

        var content = document.getElementById(contentId).innerText.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\r\n");
        var fileName = document.getElementById(fileNameId).innerText.trim();

        console.log(document.getElementById(fileNameId).innerText);

        element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(content));
        element.setAttribute('download', fileName+'.txt');

        element.style.display = 'none';
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        element.click();
        console.log(element);
        document.body.removeChild(element);
    }
</script>
```

> Note: `contentId` is a `pre` element whose text I need to download and `fileNameId`'s innerText changes dynamically, so that the downloaded file name would also change accordingly.

Now, the problem is that the `fileName` variable in JS holds extra text - 'Download1', which happens to be the value of the `data-original-title` attribute of the button. This can be seen in the o/p of console.log:

`Server Name
Download1`

Because of this, the downloaded file name becomes - `Server Name -Download1.txt`

Is this an expected behavior? How does `data-original-title`'s value end up being passed from JS when all I do is `document.getElementById(fileNameId).innerText`?

Comment: can you share the markup so that we can see the relationship between content id and filenameid?

Comment: Your code is missing something. I made a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jko48x3u/) and `document.getElementById(fileNameId).innerText` returns "Server Name" as expected. Are you using a data-binding framework of some sort?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I have edited in the question

Comment: @IanKemp I use Bootstrap3, not sure if that might be the reason, though i tried your fiddle, and it's working well. Strange!

Comment: is tooltip plugin activated in your page?its seems to me like the tooltip markup's innertext is getting mixed with other element's inner text.

Comment: Yes I use Bootstrap's tooltip functionality, and, the `data-original-title` value that appears in the file name is actually the text that appears in the tooltip box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your anchor tag before the button

```
 <li role="presentation" class="active">
        <a id="fileNameId" data-toggle="pill" href="#tab" style="font-weight:bold">Server Name
        </a>
            <button class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt text-primary tips pull-right" type="button" onclick="downloadFile('fileNameId', 'contentId')" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Download1" style="display:block"> </button>
</li>
```